# CALayer shadow while scrolling UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, calayer, shadow

I have added a shadow to a UITableView (which covers a third of the screen sfrom the bottom - see attached screenshot) using the following in a UIView Category:

`- (void) addShadow {
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:self.bounds];
    self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5,-5);
    self.layer.shadowRadius = 20;
    self.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath;
    self.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
}`

It appears as expected, but when I scroll it up, the shadow scrolls up too. Also, the table scrolls beyond its upper bound. Can you suggest what is wrong here? if I comment `self.layer.masksToBounds = NO;`, the shadow disappears, but the table scrolling is as expected. Hence, the problem lies somewhere around `masksToBounds` perhaps.

[image: Initial State]

[image: Scrolled state]

Comment: It looks like the shadow is being applied hundreds of times as the view is scrolling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by putting an identical view underneath, just for the shadow. Not a clean solution ... hence I am still open to answers. My code is as follows:

`- (UIView*) addShadow {
    UIView* backView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    UIBezierPath *path = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:backView.bounds];
    backView.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
    backView.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
    backView.layer.shadowOpacity = 1;
    backView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-5,-5);
    backView.layer.shadowRadius = 20;
    backView.layer.shadowPath = path.CGPath;
    backView.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
    [self.superview addSubview:backView];
    [self.superview bringSubviewToFront:self];
    return backView;
}`

- (void) removeShadow {
  self.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
  self.layer.shadowColor = nil;
  self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0;
  self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0,0);
  self.layer.shadowRadius = 0;
  }